# Android Billing: How to handle pending purchases

Tags: android, android-studio, android-billing

I have recently been trying to implement android in-app billing to my app. But when I use the "Test card: Decline after a few minutes" it takes many hours (~24h) before the purchase is canceled.

I have read all the documentation on the play billing library https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview and followed there implementation.

```java
public class StoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_store);

       ExtendedFloatingActionButton eFabNoAds = findViewById(R.id.efab_no_ads);
        eFabNoAds.setOnClickListener((v) -> {

            BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSkuDetails(MainActivity.skuDetailsList.get(0)).build();
            MainActivity.billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);

        });

        ExtendedFloatingActionButton eFab20Hints = findViewById(R.id.efab_20hints);
        eFab20Hints.setOnClickListener((v) -> {

            BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSkuDetails(MainActivity.skuDetailsList.get(1)).build();
            MainActivity.billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);

        });    


}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PurchasesUpdatedListener

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ....
        setupBillingClient();
    }

...

    private void setupBillingClient() {
        billingClient = BillingClient
                .newBuilder(this)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .setListener(this).build();


        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success to connect Billing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    SkuDetailsParams params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                            .setSkusList(Arrays.asList("no_ads", "hints"))
                            .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
                            .build();

                    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, (billingRes, skuDetailsList) -> {
                        if (billingRes.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                            MainActivity.skuDetailsList = skuDetailsList;


                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {

                billingClient = null;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
        //If user clicks TAP-BUY, will retrieve data here
        if (purchases != null) {

            for (Purchase p : purchases) {
                handlePurchase(p);
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, "Purchase item: " + purchases.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Purchase list empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(BillingResult billingResult) {
            Log.i(TAG, billingResult.getDebugMessage());
        }
    };

    ConsumeResponseListener consumeResponseListener = new ConsumeResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConsumeResponse(BillingResult billingResult, String purchaseToken) {
            Log.i(TAG, billingResult.getDebugMessage());

        }
    };


    void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
        if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            // Grant entitlement to the user.

            // Acknowledge the purchase if it hasn't already been acknowledged.
            if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {

                if (purchase.getSku().equals("no_ads")) {
                    AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                            AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                                    .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                                    .build();
                    billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener);

                } else {

                    ConsumeParams consumeParams = ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
                            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                            .build();

                    billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, consumeResponseListener);

                }

            }
        } else if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING) {
            // Here you can confirm to the user that they've started the pending
            // purchase, and to complete it, they should follow instructions that
            // are given to them. You can also choose to remind the user in the
            // future to complete the purchase if you detect that it is still
            // pending.

            ////// DO I NEED TO DO ANYTHING HERE? ///// 

        }
    }
}
```

I would like my users to be able to purchase how many hints as they want. And I do not want them to wait for the pending purchase to be canceled.

Is there somehow I can cancel a pending purchase? or make the user complete the purchase when he/she tries to purchase it next time?

Comment: did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Developers cannot cancel the pending order. Only users can.

If an user has a pending order, then you'll be able to tell once you call queryPurchases(). You can check the purchaseState and purchaseState.PENDING indicates that the user has a pending purchase. You can render the item button in a different way to remind user to complete the order.